# How to Call .net (WCF) web service from Netsuite Userevent script

Tags: javascript, wcf, netsuite

Please help me with this above ques. as i am new to netsuite.
Scenario is i would like to call a WCF Webserivce from Netsuite, Whenever any record has been craeted from User Event script i would like to call this webservice and send some data using post method.

Please share any example of this...

Answer (score 1):

To call the web service, I suggest using `nlapiRequestURL(url, postdata, headers, method)`, where `method` would be "POST".

For API details and usage instructions on how to use the function, you may look it up in the NetSuite Help Center.